# tabcontrol not refreshing

Tags: c#, refresh, tabcontrol, invalidation, tabpage

I have a TabControl that starts with three TabPages in it.  On the first tab there is a NumericUpDown (spinner) which displays the number of tabs and allows a user to add up to 10 extra tabs.  Once they add more than about 5 or 6 it goes beyond the width of the form and the rest of the tabs are accessible by a couple of left/right arrows at the top.  When going all the way to the right and then using the spinner to go back down to 0 (removing all the extra tabs and leave the starting three) it removes all tabs from the top of the pane and only by setting the spinner back to 1 does it refresh and display all 4 (3 from the start plus the 1 from the spinner).
I have tried several commbinations of
    `Application.DoEvents()`
    `this.Refresh()`
    `this.Invalidate()`
    `this.Update()`
but nothing seems to work.  can anybody suggest a reason why it is not updating/refreshing?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

TabPage[] tabs;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabs = new TabPage[tabControl1.Controls.Count];
        tabs[0] = tabPage1;
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numTabs = tabControl1.Controls.Count;
        decimal spinnerValue = numericUpDown1.Value;

        if (numTabs < spinnerValue) //add a tab
        {
            TabPage[] newTabs = new TabPage[(int)spinnerValue];
            for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++)
            {
                newTabs[i] = tabs[i];
            }

            TabPage tab = new TabPage("Tab " + numTabs);
            newTabs[(int)spinnerValue-1] = tab;
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
            tabs = newTabs;
        }
        else //remove a tab
        {
            TabPage[] newTabs = new TabPage[(int)spinnerValue];
            for (int i = 0; i < spinnerValue; i++)
            {
                newTabs[i] = tabs[i];
            }
            tabControl1.Controls.Remove(tabs[(int)spinnerValue]);
            tabs = newTabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like..? sounds like you have 2 issues one of them being SelectedIndex Issue and the other DoEvents() don't use that..
perhaps you can look at BeginInvoke
 if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1) {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tabControl1.SelectTab(0)));

Comment: why would there be a selectedindex issue?

Comment: I am taking a stab in the dark without any code to see how you are doing things... it's hard for anyone to give a concrete answer.. I would suggest posting some code

Comment: with the code you have ..the Program only starts out with 1 single Tab are you aware of that..?

Comment: yes, the spinner is there to control how many tabs are present

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code or knowing what type of project this is winforms, WPF, ASP.NET etc..
it's hard to give a definite answer, I am going to assume that this is WinForms

I'm not sure if you can. The following is a quote from MSDN:

"Controls contained in a TabPage are not created until the tab page is shown, and any data bindings in these controls are not activated until the tab page is shown."

However, instead of having the update code get the values from the controls directly, maybe you could create a class that could hold the Data you use to populate the controls and then when the update code is called it asks the class for the value and the class checks if the control is loaded and otherwise it gets the value from the Data instead.

Comment: how do i know what type of project this is?

Comment: well is it a web application for example do you have .aspx file? if so it's a ASP.NET project.. post some code that you are using and I am quite sure if you put in the proper Class Definition we can tell you what type of project you are using.. I honestly can't believe that you don't know what type of project you are using..

Comment: sorry new to C# ....this is a forms application.  ive replicated it within a small test app:

Comment: due to character limits I cant post it all here.  please find it at: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35363974/test.zip)

Comment: so to replicate the issue increment the spinner till its maximum (20), and then use the scroll arrows at the top to go all the way to the right.  now decrement the spinner till it gets to 1.  you can see all the tabs have dissappeared.  now increment to 2 and it refreshes the tabs at the top.  question is: how can i have it refresh properly?

Comment: I don't download .zip files from users who post on stack over flow never know what you're download or opening anyway. the only code you should post is the code that contains the logic for the winforms application.. not the entire project.. so the Methods where you feel the logic is failing

Comment: difficult to get formatting, any tips on how to post some code?

Comment: how to put in a newline?  pressng enter just adds the comment

Comment: make sure there are not any unnecessary spaces in the code and once you paste it .. hit Ctrl+K and it will format it here..
hit Shift + Enter key will add a new line in Comment you do now want to post code in the comments section just edit your original question and post the code in that section Shift+Enter should work as well adding a new line..

Comment: cheers for that, couldnt figure it our which was I put up the link...
its pretty basic, just a form with a tabcontrol 1 tabpage and i dynamically add more tabs with the spinner

Comment: I will look at this give me a few... I need to run to the store real quick and I will try your code on my local machine

Comment: I ran your code and it Starts up with One Tab.. keep in mind that that's a Tab technically the tab count should be count + 1 and reverse when removing.. not sure what you mean when you say it's not refreshing.. I can't see any errors .. I am running this in vs2010 what are you using vs 2008 or 2010 also Spinner control does not go back down to 0 if it did then it would probably error out anyway.. also what are the other Tabs suppose to have on them..? this needs to be cleaned up in regards to what you are trying to ultimately accomplish

Comment: i am also running vs2010. with this being a small test app i realize its probably not the cleanest and there is probably errors but just looking to focus on removing the tabs. if you increase the spinner it adds tabs, up to 20.  then scroll to the right using the arrows that have now become visible.  if you now use the spinner to decrease down to 1 you can see the tabs have now been removed but ALSO the remaining tab has become invisible.  if you then increase the spinner to 2 the first tab now becomes visible when the second tab is displayed.